# How to call CPack on multiple subprojects?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I have a top CMakeLists.txt that include subdirectories each having a full-fledged project. Calling `make` or `make test` will successfully call the corresponding target of each subproject.

`make package` will not. It builds the package of the last project to be processed by cmake.

How to build the packages of all the subprojects from the top project ?

Comment: Do subprojects set any CPack-related variables (prefixed with `CPACK_`)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, they do

Comment: So, this is a reason why only the last subproject is actually packaged: `CPACK_` variables are global, and setting them in one subproject overrides settings by the other. Until you remove all `CPACK_` settings from subprojects and add them to superproject, you cannot package all subprojects together.

Comment: The point is that I would like to be able to call "make package" and have packages for each subproject created, the same way "make test" calls the test of each subproject.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want. While your subprojects have consistent CTest settings, their CPack settings **conflict**. This is why `make test` call behaves as expected, but `make package` does not. Show how subprojects set `CPACK_` variables (all other cmake commands are irrelevant). Also, OS and packaging type (Deb, RPM, ...) are meaningfull.